# Total Async in Web Applications for ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asynchronous, .net-3.5

I've been informing myself about the `async` capabilities of `.net 3.5`
Ive found a very good article on this : `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx`

Now, the thing is, all these methods still require the async tasks to be finished BEFORE the `Page_Render` event, so in practice, the web application will still appear to be 'hanging' for the user.

**My question:** How can I `async` launch a heavy task from my `aspx` page, without having to wait or `callback` for this task when its finished, and then just render the page. The actual work is being done in a `WCF` service ( creating document, sending mail )

Pseudo code:

```
void btn_Click()
{
   AsyncCallWcfServiceButDontWaitForIt();
   lblFeedback.Text = "Your documents are beging generated and mailed in the background";  
}
```

I'd like to give the user direct feedback while the rest is being handled in the background. I've implemented something like this with executing a `console script` but I'm looking for a possible better `async` way.

Please also note I'm looking for a `.NET 3.5` solution!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is *not* async here (though you should also be doing that)... what you are looking for is AJAX; you render the page, then load the slow-loading information via Ajax (with async code, just as usual)

Comment: problem is, I need lots of data from the user controls which I can't do in my WebMethod + Also, can you predict the behaviour what will happen when the user will see the feedback and immediately closes the window? I want the async task to always finish, even in the background.